# WCF Azure create PDF file in virtual directory with DevExpress

Tags: c#, azure, pdf

We have a wcf service that uses DevExpress XtraReports to generate a pdf file.

How this normally works is we have in the web.config the physical directory Example C:\PdfDocs\ that we specify as the path when executing the devexpress ExportToPdf function. This works fine on a normal virtual machine.

We are now busy moving to Microsoft Azure enviroment and I am having trouble getting this to work.

My Setup - The wcf service is created as a App Service. Unfortunately I am not at liberty to give names so lets assume the following:

App Service Name - testdocservice, 
Url Azure gives - https://testdocservices.azurewebsites.net

What I have tried:

In Application settings, I have created a virtual directory. In the project itself I have created a folder that the virtual directory will point to.

The virtual path is https://testdocservices.azurewebsites.net/ItinDocs and the physical path is site\wwwroot\ItinDocuments

This is setup correctly as I have tested it by FTP test pdf in and then hit the following url: https://testdocservices.azurewebsites.net/ItinDocs/test.pdf

So in the wcf service I took a chance and set the location to render the pdf to "site\wwwroot\ItinDocuments" - This did not work.

The exception was as follows: Access to the path 'D:\Windows\system32\site\wwwroot\ItinDocuments\TestQuote21.pdf' is denied.

I then tried using Server.MapPath example:

```
QuoteV3 oQuote = new QuoteV3();
            oQuote.DataSource = dSource;
            oQuote.ExportToPdf(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"~{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocLocation"]}{fileName}"));
```

The DocLocation look like the following: site\wwwroot\ItinDocuments\

This also did not work. The following error is given:

'~https:/testdocservices.azurewebsites.net/ItinDocs/TestQuote21.pdf' is not a valid virtual path.

I thought the first character "~" could be a problem so I removed it and got the same error as above - 'https:/testdocservices.azurewebsites.net/ItinDocs/TravelQuote21.pdf' is not a valid virtual path.

I then noticed that the above errors only have one forward-slash after the https. At this point I am not sure if that could be causing the problem and then how to correct it as the Server.MapPath is generating that part.

In conclusion, I am not sure if I am even working in the right direction with the above approach. My knowledge around azure is still minimal.

Any help/assistance/solution would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be closed as I have instead setup azure storage and my pdfs are saving in a container instead.

Thanks.